# Getting correct context for binding knockoutjs in typescript

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I am trying to use KnockoutJS and Typescript but run into an issue getting the right context for `this` (the class Test) inside my click binding `clickMe`.

I have come up with two ways, the first way I can call a function on my `Test` class by using `Test.prototype.LoadNextWinner`...

```
 module Swagolicious {

     export class Test {

         constructor() {
             this.WireUp();
         }

         private WireUp() {
             var instance = new this.ViewModel();
             ko.applyBindings(instance);
         }

        private ViewModel = function() {
            var vm = this;
            vm.clickMe = () => {
                //This is one way to call function LoadNextWinner
                Test.prototype.LoadNextWinner(vm);
            };
         }

         private LoadNextWinner(vm) {
             console.log("clicked");
             console.log(vm);
         }
     }
 }


 $(() => {
     var test = new Swagolicious.Test();
 });
```

alternatively the second way is I can send the current context `this` as a parameter into the view model. e.g.  `var instance = new this.ViewModel(this);`

```
 module Swagolicious {

     export class Test {

         constructor() {
             this.WireUp();
         }

         private WireUp() {
             //or I can send this into the ViewModel
             var instance = new this.ViewModel(this);
             ko.applyBindings(instance);
         }

        private ViewModel = function(instance) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.clickMe = () => {
                //This is another way to call function LoadNextWinner
                instance.LoadNextWinner(vm);
            };
         }

         private LoadNextWinner(vm) {
             console.log("clicked");
             console.log(vm);
         }
     }
 }


 $(() => {
     var test = new Swagolicious.Test();
 });
```

However both ways seem a little dirty to me, the first way I am calling the function directly with protoype and the second way (YUK) I am sending `this` as a context into the view model.

My button is simply:-

```
<button data-bind="click : clickMe">Click me</button>
```

I have tried all different ways of getting the class context of `TEST` but so far have failed to do so. What other options do I have?

Comment: The problem is that you are binding knockout to an instance of ViewModel, but the clickMe callback needs access to the instance of the Test class.  That is the reason you need to supply the instance so it can be accessed in the closure.  Why the nested ViewModel class and not put clickMe directly on the Test class ( still use an Arrow function and the "this" Typescript context will be the instance of the Test class ) and applyBind the Test instance ?

Comment: Simply for the reason that the click function is doing quite a lot of stuff and shares functionality with other actions. To keep dry is my main reason.  As a matter of interest with method do you prefer?